# after pushing the image outside card, it shows only half

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is my sample output, as you can see here that the image is half.

[image]

The second photo provided is the output i'm trying to achieve.

[image]

I don't know what seems to be the problem here, but when i remove the class, "carousel-inner" the image output is complete, but when i put it back, it shows only half image.

this is my html code and i'm using bootstrap 4

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="customer-card">
          <div class="customer-img">
            <img src="assets/img/user-img/john.png" alt="customer image" class="">
          </div>
          <div class="customer-txt-area">
            <p class="john">"With Finger Food, my birthday party was a real blast! Super finger food!"</p>
              <h4><b>John Esacada</b></h4>
              <small>Sydney</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div> 
   </div>
 </div>
```

```css
.customer-card-parent{
  margin-top: 41px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 964px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.customer-card{ 
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 290px;
  padding: 39px 0px 35px 0px;  
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;  
} 
.customer-img{
  position:absolute;
  top: -55px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 11px solid #fff;
  background-color: #cecece;
}
.customer-img img{
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto;  
  position: relative;
  top: 21px; 
  transform: scale(1.4, 1.3);
} 
.customer-txt-area .john{
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #696969; 
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 18px; 
  line-height: 23px;
  font-family: "MyriadPro";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just now, i managed to somehow "solved" the issue here without changing any css. I just added some classes to my carousel-inner.

as you can see in this photo, i added border class to my carousel-inner class in order to see the actual "height" and "width" of my div and it shows like this.

[image]

```html
<div class="carousel-inner border ">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="customer-card">
          <div class="customer-img">
            <img src="assets/img/user-img/john.png" alt="customer image" class="">
          </div>
          <div class="customer-txt-area">
            <p class="john">"With Finger Food, my birthday party was a real blast! Super finger food!"</p>
            <h4><b>John Esacada</b></h4>
            <small>Sydney</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div>  
</div>
```

So, i tried adding some classes to my carousel-inner

```html
<div class="carousel-inner border d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="customer-card">
          <div class="customer-img">
            <img src="assets/img/user-img/john.png" alt="customer image" class="">
          </div>
          <div class="customer-txt-area">
            <p class="john">"With Finger Food, my birthday party was a real blast! Super finger food!"</p>
            <h4><b>John Esacada</b></h4>
            <small>Sydney</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div>  
</div>
```

and now it shows something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
.customer-img
{
  position:absolute;
  top: -55px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 11px solid #fff;
  background-color: #cecece;
}
```

you have to remove "overflow: hidden;" from the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `overflow: hidden;` from the parent element, which is ".customer-img" in your case and remember to add padding of half the size of the image to ".customer-card" parent element  .

Comment: Thank you for the idea Mr. Rohan. I did try removing it and sadly still shows half image.

Answer (score 1):

```
.customer-img{
  position:absolute;
  top: -55px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
```

`top:-55px` is pushing the image out of the card and since abolute position is used, height of card doesn't consider image height so use min-height or height for card.

```
.customer-card{ 
  width: 100%;
  min-height:300px;
  max-width: 290px;
  padding: 39px 0px 35px 0px;  
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea Mr. Ezekiel. i tried to apply these but it didn't turn out the way it should be. Still, thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

**Add here**

```
<div class="row">
```

**Extra style**

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px">
```